# Upgrade vSphere 6.0 standard to 6.5

Tags: vmware-vsphere

I have several ESXi hosts that running vSphere version 6.0 standard licenses. Now, I have a plan to upgrade all of that to vSphere version 6.5. I'm not sure to upgrade to vSphere 6.5 for free. Can I upgrade to 6.5 for free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, VMware 6.0 and 6.5 use the same license. You can upgrade for free.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, it's free. Also go over these before upgrading, it's important considerations before upgrading: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2147548